# How to present analytic information to advertisers?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, advertising

We are planning to sell ads directly to the advertisers.

What is the best way to present website analytic information to the advertisers?

If it makes any difference, we are using Google Analytics.

Comment: check out http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/embeddedanalyticsforadvertisers.html  A ton of advertisers use our widgets on their "Advertise with Us" pages.   I could provide you additional references than the ones listed on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them (read-only) access to the account. Anything less and some may be tempted to suspect that you're fudging the numbers. If they aren't able to handle analytics, make them nice powerpoints, but let them know they have access to the raw data anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to limit their access to certain reports and not all of them?

Comment: Yes. You can create "properties" and "views" of all sorts, decide what belongs there and only give access to the respective selection.